# How did the system not catch these two <30 character answers?

Tags: support, bug, answers, character-limit

A few days ago, I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66019566/13138080) answer, and thought nothing of the fact that it had <30 characters (including zero-width spaces and HTML tags and other Unicode characters).  But then I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66080461/13138080) answer, which was also posted with less than 30 characters, and it reminded me.  When I try to post something like that, I get:

[image]

That also shows if I try to edit in a single extra character, indicating there aren't any invisible characters.  Why were these two posts allowed?  Was it just a brief system fart?

Comment: Is this one of those cases where the restriction is only client side?

Comment: Cross-site dupe: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404931/why-did-the-system-allow-this-short-answer-30-characters-to-be-posted

Comment: Maybe they're posted using the app, which has no client side validation, or borked validation.

Comment: Ya, the app allows for some funny things. You can submit answers to questions long after they've been closed if you opened the answer dialog before it was closed.

Comment: @Carcigenicate but that's status-bydesign anyway, for 4 hours at least...